# Remote desktop access enabling from terminal in Powershell

Tags: ssh, windows, rdp, powershell

I am accessing my Ubuntu 19 workstation from my Win 10 home computer through Powershell. My remote desktop is not enabled in Ubuntu and I can't access remmina or anything that requires GUI like xRDP or VNC. I also can't access my Workstation now. Can I turn on remote desktop access from Powershell and then use win remote desktop connection?

Comment: Can you access your workstation via SSH? If yes you can easily enable RDP using the command line.

Comment: I can access viaSSH but Remmina, VNC and vino seem to require a GUI popup to change preferences, from all the searched that I performed. I am sorry, I'm new to Ubuntu. If you can, please tell me know how to enable RDP from command line alone in remmina. Thanks!